# Needing a little help performing operations on remote repository

Tags: libgit2sharp

I've been tinkering around, and reading through what little Wiki information that I could find, and looked through tests that I thought may be relevant, however I'm having problems coming up with a working solution for a few things.

Mostly, I'm looking for a way to list commits that have been pushed to the server ahead of your working repository / local commits. I've tried using Fetch, and FetchHeads, but looking through all of the documentation for the Network class doesn't seem to yield anything that I can understand, I guess. Ideally, I'd be interested in seeing something like:

```
    IQueriableCommitLog Repository.Network.GetCommitsAhead
```

OR

```
    IQueriableCommitLog Repository.Remote.GetCommitsAhead
```

Then, just use the results like you would in:

```
    IQueriableCommitLog Repository.Commits
```

Also, perhaps a method like Commit.UpdateTo() for the remote commit.

Am I too far off base for what I'm looking for? Is it possible at this time to perform actions such as this? Is it supported by libgit2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mostly, I'm looking for a way to list commits that have been pushed to the server ahead of your working repository / local commits.

A `Branch` is either local or remote. Local `Branch`es which are tracking other ones expose a `TrackedBranch` property.

Considering a local **branch** with a not null `TrackedBranch` property

- Commits that have been performed on this local branch and aren't known from the tracked one.

`repo.Commits.QueryBy(new Filter { Since = branch.Tip, Until = branch.TrackedBranch });`

- Commits that exist in the tracked branch and aren't known from the local one

`repo.Commits.QueryBy(new Filter { Since = TrackedBranch, Until = Tip })`

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the first code block is for local commits that are unknown to the server, and second block ones that are known to the server, but unknown to your working copy?

Comment: Yes. However, please keep in mind that this will work against what your local repository knows about the state of the remote server. If you need updated information, make sure to issue a `Fetch()` first.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, however TrackedBranch always reports null.

`repo = new Repository( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() );`
`repo.Fetch( "origin" );`

`branch = repo.Head;`

Comment: Actually, I fixed it by doing an actual clone of the repository. I believe the test repo was created with an init command, instead of an actual clone, and this must be why TrackedBranch returns null.

Well done, thanks for the assist.