# Can't update from a remote repository after having local changes

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm currently trying to update my local repository from a remote one.
This works as long as I don't have any local changes in my files.

```
using (var r = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(repo))
{
    var options = new MergeOptions
    {
        MergeFileFavor = MergeFileFavor.Theirs,
    };
    var result = r.Network.Pull(localSignature, new PullOptions { MergeOptions = options });
}
```

I found that answer before: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701119/needing-a-little-help-performing-operations-on-remote-repository).

However, while trying this with the above code, it's just marking my repo as "Up2Date" (status of the result) instead of actually merging my local changes with the remote updates.

How can I actually achieve this?

Comment: When you say "local changes" do you mean committed changes, staged changes or unstaged changes?  Can you show some git commands, including the `git status` that leads up to this?

Comment: Here's the git status output: http://privatepaste.com/05b9b25a61

Comment: Can you show some git commands that you are *not* up-to-date and there are really changes to Pull?